# How can i push/add blank workbook(sheet) in oneDrive in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to add a workbook from the locale machine to one drive because there is no option for creating a directly new file there.

can anyone suggest a way or Endpoints for uploading the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Upload or replace the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api by calling *PUT /me/drive/root:/Name.xlsx:/content* for example. See a the PUT request below.

```
req.put("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Book.xlsx:/content", data=contents, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format("token")})
```

Note that the contents here is the binary of the empty workbook.